# Замена результата регулярного выражения на рандомное число

Tags: javascript

Как заменить то, что нашла регулярка, на рандомное число от 0 до 9?

Comment: Что вы уже попробовали?

Comment: Заменить на плейсхолдер, а потом обычным Replace. Альтернативный вариант - динамическое формирование шаблона замены.

Comment: @Akina, функция repalce вполне понимает регулярки. поэтому можно сразу на нужное менять

Comment: @Grundy Тогда уж лучше сразу использовать вариант `replace(regexp, function)`...

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = 'привет привет омлет';
var result = input.replace(/привет/g,function() { 
    return parseInt(Math.random(0,9)*10); 
  });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) не принимает параметров, поэтому вызов `Math.random(0,9)` работает так же как и `Math.random()`